# Linq casting Issue in EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

Hi,
I am new to Linq and entity framework. I am doing something like this
I have 3 viewmodel:

1.

```
public class FlowViewModel
{
   ..........................
    public List<FlowLevelViewModel> Levels { get; set; }
}

public class FlowLevelViewModel
{
    .........................
    public List<BlockDetailsViewmodel> Blocks { get; set; }
}
public class BlockDetailsViewmodel
{
    .......................
}
```

and from my controller I am calling the datalayer.

```
var model = new FlowViewModel();
        model = dataOb.GetFlowForTheDocument(company, docType);
        model = dataOb.GetFlowStageForTheDocument(model);
        return model;
```

and in my datalayer

```
    public FlowViewModel GetFlowStageForTheDocument(FlowViewModel model)
    {
        var flowlevelviewModel = (from p in dbContext.FlowStages 
                             where p.FlowID == model.FlowId 
                             select new FlowLevelViewModel()
                              {
                               .................
                         Blocks = GetBlockDetailsForTheDocument(p.StageID, .StageType)
                              }).ToList();

        model.Levels = flowlevelviewModel;
        return model;
    }
    public List<BlockDetailsViewmodel> GetBlockDetailsForTheDocument(int StageID, string stageType)
    {
        var blockDetails = new List<BlockDetailsViewmodel>();
        ......................................
        return blockDetails;
    }
```

While I am running the program I am getting this error:

```
**NotSupportedException Was unhandled by user Code**
    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SEADViewModel.BlockDetailsViewmodel] GetBlockDetailsForTheDocument(Int32, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

My project is in production stage so I have no time at all. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
var data = (from p in dbContext.FlowStages 
                             where p.FlowID == model.FlowId 
                             select p).ToList();
var flowlevelviewModel = (from p in data
                          select new FlowLevelViewModel()
                              {
                               .................
                         Blocks = GetBlockDetailsForTheDocument(p.StageID, .StageType)
                              }).ToList();
```

Note that this will evaluate the query at the first `ToList()`. If you need to run the entire query at once, you need to build a simple LINQ expression, you can't use your method  `GetBlockDetailsForTheDocument` inside the query. See @Tilak's answer for a link to supported build in methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx).

It does not support all the functions. [List of supported and non supported functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

You need to write [custom model defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx) `GetBlockDetailsForTheDocument` to use it in LINQ query.